# Conditional summation in time-to-event data

Tags: stata

I have the following data that has been prepared with `stset`. The resulting variables signify cohort entry and exit times along with event status. In addition, a numerical variable - `prob` has been calculated based on the riskset size.

For those subjects that are not cases (where _d == 0), I need to sum all values of the `prob` variable where `_t` falls within that subject's follow-up time.

For example, subject 8 enters the cohort at _t0 == 0 and exits at _t == 8. Between these times, there are three `prob` values 0.9, 0.875 and 0.875 - giving the desired answer for subject 8 as 2.65.

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. To install: ssc install dataex
clear
input long id byte(_t0 _t _d) float prob
 1 0  1 0        .
 2 0  2 0        .
 3 1  3 1       .9
 4 0  4 0        .
 5 0  5 1     .875
 6 0  6 1     .875
 7 5  7 0        .
 8 0  8 0        .
 9 0  9 1 .8333333
10 0 10 1       .8
11 0 11 0        .
12 8 12 1 .6666667
13 0 13 0        .
14 0 14 0        .
15 0 15 0        .
end
```

The desired output would return all of the data with an additional variable signifying the summed values of `prob`.

Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: Thank you for sharing the data. Could you add a definition of each variable, and clarify what you want to sum? In particular, are you trying to create one variable for each subject?

Comment: @ArthurMorris - thanks for the help. Each subject has a _t0 and _t value defining the start and end of their follow-up time. I would like to sum all values of prob within this follow-up time. Only the subjects where _d == 1 have a prob value. Prob values at time _t  - e.g. prob == 0.9 is generated at time == 3. I think for each subject I would need to filter all the prob values by that subject's _t0 and _t - something I don't know how to do.

Comment: Is there a subject id variable? In general it seems like the example data doesn't have all of the variables that we need to complete the task.